# Dynamic font color assignment based on a form field value in Acrobat

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I have a loan form that calculates a debt:income ratio.  I want the field the ration is in (calculated field, no user input allowed) to change the font color based on the ratio.

If the ratio is above 60%, then I want the font color to be an off-red (see color values below), another color if >= 35%, and normal if below 35%.

This is the code I've come up with...

```
if (event.value >= .6) {
    this.textColor = (255, 153, 0);
}
else if (event.value >= .35) {
    this.textColor = (204, 51, 0);
}
else {
    this.textColor = (0, 102, 153);
}
```

The code is in a custom validation.

This doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the `vResult` actually a `number`, and not a `string` representation of one?

Comment: I changed the code to use event.value instead.

Comment: My question still applies, whether it really is a number or not, as if not it won't work.

Comment: Yes, the event.value evaluates to a number, formatted as a percentage in the form.  I need to be able to change the font color based on its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were several problems with your code but also, you were running it in the wrong event. During a validation event, the value isn't actually committed yet. Use a custom Format script to change the appearance of a field after the value has been committed. See image.
[image]

Then in your code, you need to get the value of the field triggering the script (event.target) and then you need to set the color property of it (event.target.textColor). Also, colors in PDF are defined by using an array where the first element is the color space, then followed by values that range from 0 to 1. See revised code below.

```
if (event.target.value >= .6) {
    event.target.textColor = ["RGB", 255/255, 153/255, 0];
}
else if (event.target.value >= .35) {
    event.target.textColor = ["RGB", 204/255, 51/255, 0];
}
else {
    event.target.textColor = ["RGB", 0, 102/255, 153/255];
}
```

Comment: That seems reasonable, however, it seems like this answer would only apply to Acrobat XI.  I am using X Pro and it doesn't have the option to create a custom format script.

Is there a work-around?

ANSWER:  I placed everything in the custom calculation script and it works like a charm.  Thank you.  Marked as accepted.

Comment: Custom format scripts have been around since version 3.5 and the UI has been the same since then. If you've already set the format to Number, you won't be able to set it though. You need to set the format category to "Custom"... just like in the screen shot I posted.

Comment: In addition to @joelgeraci 's comment, this same code may also work in the Validate event, or you can include it into your calculation. If neither is acceptable, you would use util.printf() to format the field's value.